# datastore download/export to local file

Tags: export, localhost, datastore

I am trying to download/export datastore data to a local file of any kind ie txt. xls. I have read all the info I can find but just need a quick method to export

Comment: which query language you use? SPARQL?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on which datastore you use.
if you are using stardog, It gives you command line feature to export to rdf format.

```
$ stardog export -c myDatabase --format RDFXML myDatabase_output.rdf
```

If you wanted to export to txt or xls format. you have to query the datastore and write the resulltset into a file.